# Change Screen Density in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am debugging my app in my real device connected through USB into Android Studio. Problem is that my device has a resolution of 720x1280 with 320dpi (xhdpi). In which particularly some elements in the app is a bit scaled. Since my workspace in Android Studio has a resolution of 1080x1920 420dpi. I want to change it to my device's 720. I tried creating my own profile below:
[image]

But I noticed there is no option to change the dpi. It's still 420, in which I want to change as 320.I also tried going to the **Run>Edit Configurations** but to no avail. Is there anyway I can do this?

## Update

What I meant is to change the **Device in Editor**'s dpi. Since it is defaulted into either 420dpi or xhdpi. I need to change it to 320dpi to fit my phone's.

Comment: [Android density](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) Support different pixel densities you can go to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in Android Studio to change android virtual device screen density. At least not in the latest version, currently Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1.

You can change the density by editing the file `~/.android/avd/my_avd/config.ini`. Find the line hw.lcd.density and change the value to one of the following that are supported: `120, 160, 213, 240, 280, 320, 360, 400, 420, 480, 560, 640`.

Answer (score -1):

Create New Hardware Profile & add Resolution 800 * 1280 and set as new device

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xwpP.png)

Reference 
[Reference here](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-density-independent-pixel-sp-dp-dip-in-android)